# bootstrap push and pull

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, push, pull

I'm creating a site with Bootstrap and I have a question. I would like to `pull` and `push` `column`s and to use some like "more" of the 12 `column`s, is it possible? On a Mobile version it would put a 3rd `column` on one of the next `row`. Maybe the `image` below would be helpful.

```
DESKTOP
---------------------------
|     1           --------|---------
| ----------      | 2     |        |
| |3       |      |       |        |
| ----------      |       |        |
---------------------------        |
                  |                |
                  ------------------
Reverse version
         ---------------------------
---------|--------    1            |
|        |       |      ---------- |
|2       |       |      |3       | |
|        |       |      ---------- |
|        ---------------------------
|                |
------------------
Mobile
---------------------------
|1  ------------------    |
|   | 2              |    |
|   |                |    |
|   |                |    |
---------------------------
    |                |
    ------------------
---------- 
| 3      |
----------
```

I tried something like this but I don't know how I can do a reverse `row`. Reverse `class` doesn't work with `div` inside of a `div`, and that's why I want to put 1 and 2 `column`s on the regular `column`s next to each other and use `pull` and `push`, but the second `column` walks down. I don't know how export the 3rd `column` out of the `row`.

```css
.webbg {
 height: 30vw;
 background-color: aqua;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 max-height: 75vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid my-5">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 offset-md-0 offset-lg-1 webbg" style="background-color: aqua;">
 <div class="col-3"><h3 class="text-uppercase"><strong>sometext</strong></h3></div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 offset-sm-0 col-md-12 col-lg-12 offset-md-4 offset-lg-4 offset-xl-7">
  <img src="http://www.tweaks.pl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/aoc-u3477pqu.png" class="img-fluid">
 </div> 
 </div>
 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.  Are you asking if you can use offsets to push a column outside the boundaries of the `.row` wrapper class?

Comment: In mobile I would like to keep 1 and 2 column in the same line and put 3rd column outside row.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your clarification you want Column A and Column B to collapse to each take 1/2 the `.row` on small devices, with Column C taking up the whole space below.  And (I assume) on larger screens they each take up an equal amount of space?

That being the case, this is *basic* Bootstrap Grid responsive design.  Things changed slightly in Bootstrap 4 as they flipped to Flexbox so you should definitely reorient yourself with Grid Syntax:

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

To achieve the layout as described above you would use code similar to the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4" style="background:#999">A</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4" style="background:#777">B</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4" style="background:#555">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The way the code above reads is as follows:

> For A and B, use a '6 of 12' column for the smallest breakpoint.  For
>   'medium' and greater use a '4 of 12' column.  For C use a full column
>   for the smallest breakpoint.  For 'medium' and greater use a '4 of 12'
>   column.

You can adjust as needed but if your intention is that on medium and greater every column displays in the same row the must add up to 12.

Comment: I have to push 3-rd column  outside first column in the mobile version. I can use hidden-sm-down and hidden-sm-up but i don't want put second the same text.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question you're asking here.  If you need to re-order the columns based on breakpoints Bootstrap 4 does have the `.order-*-*` class...